# How to control JButton in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on a GUI of Swing.

I have a `JPanel`: 4 `JTextField` and a `JButton` inside.

the button will be enable when all of the four `JTextField` are not empty. And the button should be disable when any of the four textfield is empty.

my solution is:
  `addDocumentListener` for all of the 4 textfiled. when one of the textfield changed, I will check all of the 4 textfiled and decide whether enable the button or not.
It works **but seems ugly**....

```
private void buttonAlter() {
    if( !textField1.getText().isEmpty() && !textField2.getText().isEmpty() && !textField3.getText().isEmpty() && !textField4.getText().isEmpty()) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }else {
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

//for all the textfields
textField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        buttonAlter();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        buttonAlter();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

    }
});
```

Do we have another better way to do this thing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can add the same listener to your 4 text fields.

Comment: A `DocumentListener` is the only way to be sure that every change to a textfield is noticed. Alternatives might miss actions performed by the context menu, like cut or paste, or miss a machine-event like `textField1.setText()`

Answer (score 3):

Reuse your code, do not repeat yourself.

Make a collection of all the textFields:

```
Collection<JTextField> textFields = Arrays.asList(textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4);
```

Later you can use it for enabling/disabling:

```
private void buttonAlter() {
    boolean allFilled = true;
    for (JTextField textField : textFields)
         allFilled &= !textField.getText().isEmpty();

    button.setEnabled(allFilled);
}
```

and for listeners:

```
// create one, single listener, store it in a variable
DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        buttonAlter();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        buttonAlter();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

    }
}

// use that same listener for all textFields
for (JTextField textField : textFields)
     textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same `Document Listener` to your `JTextFields`. For example.

```
DocumentListener dL = new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        buttonAlter();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         buttonAlter();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

    }
};

textField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dL);
textField2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dL);
textField3.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dL);
textField4.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dL);
```

Answer (score 0):

> It works but seems ugly....

Yes, because you:

1. hard code the listener for every text field.
2. hard code the text fields in the if condition

Both of the above problems do not allow for a dynamic number of text fields.

Here is a reusable solution that allows you to use any number of text fields for a specific button:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DataEntered implements DocumentListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public DataEntered(JButton button)
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
    {
        textFields.add( textField );
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

    public boolean isDataEntered()
    {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields)
        {
            if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void checkData()
    {
        button.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JButton submit = new JButton( "Submit" );
        submit.setEnabled( false );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        DataEntered de = new DataEntered( submit );
        de.addTextField( textField1 );
        de.addTextField( textField2 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look on [Java Swing Builder](https://github.com/jacek99/javabuilders). I'm pretty sure you will be surprised.